# No grub menu in Ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: grub2

I'm pretty sure I have 18.04 Ubuntu Server.  But when I press the shift key and wait until reboot is finished it come to the same log in screen with my user name.  I input what I believe is my password. It states it is incorrect.I reboot pressing the shit key, holding until the menu shows up and I'm back to the log in screen.  At no time does the grub menu come up.

Answer (score 1):

To show Grub 2 menu at boot only the right hand <kbd>Shift</kbd>. key works. In EFI boot <kbd>Esc</kbd> key works.

Once you get the grub you can change the password in in Advanced Options > Recovery Mode > Drop to root shell prompt.

Comment: It's a new install.  I tried the right and the left.  Decided to reinstall.

Comment: Holding the Esc key takes me to the `grub>` prompt, not to the Grub 2 menu